# Navigation Button HTML and java script

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a navigation button for my website. Using regular hyperlinks works in order to access the other other html files however using a button and script to navigate does nothing.

This is my code, please tell me what I did wrong.

```
<html id="html">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HomePageStyle.css">
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="container">
    <header>
    <ul>
        <li><button onclick = "html&css()">HTML & CSS</button></li>
        <li><a href="SQLPage.html">SQL</a></li>
        <li><a href="JavaScriptPage.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="PerlPage.html">Perl & Server Side Scripting</a></li>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kosugi+Maru|Poor+Story" rel="stylesheet">
    </ul>
      <script>
function html&css() {
    window.location.href = 'Html&CssPage.html';
}
</script>
```

Comment: The ampersand is causing a problem there. Check the list of operators of JavaScript or any of the popular languages. The fix would be to change `html&css` to `htmlAndCss`. You can also check your browser console and see that it's complaining about the & symbol.

Comment: it was the "&" thanks